# Lighttpd can not start when including mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, freebsd, lighttpd

Here is my server modules list (`modules.conf`), its working without any problems, and lighttpd is running correctly while using this list:

```
server.modules = (
  "mod_access",
#  "mod_alias",
#  "mod_auth",
#  "mod_evasive",
#  "mod_redirect",
#  "mod_rewrite",
#  "mod_setenv",
#  "mod_usertrack",
)
```

The problem appears, when I want to uncomment the `mod_rewrite` module:

```
server.modules = (
  "mod_access",
#  "mod_alias",
#  "mod_auth",
#  "mod_evasive",
#  "mod_redirect",
   "mod_rewrite",
#  "mod_setenv",
#  "mod_usertrack",
)
```

Then I'm getting the following message, when I want to run my web server:

> 2012-05-01 15:01:18: (plugin.c.169) dlopen() failed for:
>   /usr/local/lib/lighttpd/mod_indexfile, mod_access.so Cannot open
>   "/usr/local/lib/lighttpd/mod_indexfile, mod_access.so"
>
> 2012-05-01 15:01:18: (server.c.656) loading plugins finally failed
>   /usr/local/etc/rc.d/lighttpd: WARNING: failed to start lighttpd

As you can see, it does have some problems with the `mod_access` module, but its strange a little bit, especially when I comment back the `mod_rewrite` module then its working.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm equally confused by what you're reporting here. Can you give a bit more information? `ls -l /usr/local/lib/lighttpd`

Comment: Confused as in it makes no sense why lighttpd would be failing that way, not confused by your description of the problem*

Comment: @DavidSouther Sure, here is the output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=b44myTzG

Comment: Hm, gee surprise our installs look rather different ;) What version of lighttpd, and what is your host platform?

Comment: `1.4.30` installed using ports , dedicated server running on FreeBSD 8.2.

Comment: `mod_indexfile` is loaded by default which can be a little confusing.  I'm guessing there's another mention of `server.modules` somewhere in your config file(s).  Can you post them?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this problem with the latest [www/lighttpd](http://www.freshports.org/www/lighttpd) port (version 1.4.32) and could not... The server starts with the modules.conf as you describe. Try updating to the latest, and if that works for you too, then just chalk it up as a bug of 1.4.30 and move on...